# Why does constraining a SKCamera to a SKSpriteNode not work?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to have the camera of the scene constrained to the player.

The following code doesn't work. The camera just stands still when the player moves:

```
let mainCamera = SKCameraNode()

let range = SKRange(lowerLimit: 0, upperLimit: 0)

let constraint = SKConstraint.distance(range, to: player)
constraint.enabled = true

mainCamera.constraints = [constraint]

camera = mainCamera
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: You need to also add the camera to the scene

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Why? the camera works without adding it to the scene. I can move it manually but the constraints just don't apply.

Comment: Because it is not a part of the scene, so you are constraining nothing

Comment: From the looks of your code,  all you need to do is add the camera to the player, no need for a constraint

Comment: @Knight0fDragon oh okay, that worked, thank you